I have to find some arc measures based on the angles between intersecting chords and some given arc measures.

A circle with points E, F, A, B, C, and D. There are 3 chords, chord EC, chord FB, and Chord AD, none of which are diameters. Chord FB and chord AD intersect at a 90 degree angle, and chord EC intersects chord AD at point H. This forms an 115 degree angle facing outward. The arc measure of DC is 85 degrees, and the arc measure for EF is 20 degrees. Chord FB extends out to point J, forming a right triangle between Point G (located at the intersection of FB and AD), point J, and point A. Angle GAJ is equal to 60 degrees.
Above is a picture of the problem. I need to solve for the measure in degrees of arc ED and arc AB. I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried using the rule that says the angle that is formed by two intercepting arcs is equal to 1/2 times the length of the arc subtended by the angle vertical to the angle plus the length of the arc subtended by the angle. I did not seem to have enough information to do this, and have not found another way yet.
I am sorry if I formatted anything wrong, this is my first time asking something on this platform. I'm also not very good at talking about things in math terms. Thank you for your help.

We can find that (Angle EHA) equals 65° based on 115+x=180 because they are supplementary angles.
With the Angles Inside Circle Theorem, (Angle EHG)=1/2((Arc CD)+(Arc EA)). So, 65=1/2(x+85), and (Arc EA)=45°.
Knowing that (Arc EJ)+(Arc JA)=(Arc EA), 20+x=45. So, (Arc FA)=25.
Knowing that all angles in a triangle add up to 180, (Angle AJF)=30°.
Now using the Angles Outside the Circle Theorem, (Angle AJF)=1/2((Arc AB)-(Arc AF)). So, 30=1/2(x-25), and (Arc AB)=85°. This is the first part of the problem completed.
Using the Angles Inside Circle Theorem again, (Angle DGB)=1/2((Arc FA)+(Arc DB)). So, 90=1/2(25+x), and (Arc DB)=155°.
And finally, knowing that all arcs in a circle add up to 360, (Arc ED)+(Arc EA)+(Arc AB)+(Arc DB)=360. So x+45+85+155=360, and (Arc ED)=75

Thank You very much!
